# Checking clients connection quality to TIdTCPServer in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, networking, indy10

Using Delphi 10, I have a `TIdTCPServer` that receives connections from various clients, some are Windows clients, others are mobile (iOS and Android).

Is there a way to determine the connection quality between an Indy TCP server and Indy TCP client connected to that server?

I tried with `TIdICMPClient`, but the thing is that some Windows clients block the ping with their firewalls.

I should specify a code for the question to be posted .. so ..

```
function Testquality: boolean;
begin
  IdIcmpClient1.ReceiveTimeout := 500;
  IdIcmpClient1.Host := host;
  IdIcmpclient1.OnReply := PingReply;
  IdIcmpClient1.Ping;
  Result := IdIcmpClient1.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType <> rsTimeout;
end;
```

Comment: What kind of "connection quality" are you looking for exactly?  You already have established TCP connections, there is no need to resort to ICMP. If you want to know if the clients are still alive and responsive, have the server send a command down each connection and require the clients to send a response back (or vice versa, have each client send a command that the server responds to). Do this periodically, and have the server close any connections that are not responding (or not sending commands often enough).  If that is not an option for your apps, at least enable TCP-level keepalives.

Comment: Remy thank you for answering.. i need to , in a scale of bars(1 bar, 2 or 3 bars for good connection speed) represent the link quality of each of the connected clients.. just like in icmp a result of 300 ms is considered high ping (low internet) and 40-100 is considered fair ping.. you got me ??

Comment: There is nothing like that in TCP.  All you can do is send a command to the other side and clock how long it takes to respond, repeating that several times and averaging the durations.

Comment: Someone gave me an idea.. of letting the client ping the server and send that resultt back to the server.. it's reasonable tthis way.. dont you think ??

Comment: Like you said earlier, ICMP pings can be blocked, so it doesn't make much sense to have a client try to determine and report its own status back to the server. You really need to handle this inside your TCP communication protocol itself. Have the server send its own `PING` like commands for clients to respond to. Or have clients send their own `PING` like commands for the server to response to. One way or the other, this allows both client and server to check that the other party is still alive and see how responsive it is.

Comment: Ok.. thanks man.. u're always here to help... thanx a lot.. iwill do tthat